# Opening popup from swipe view

Tags: android, popup, swipe

I am trying to open a popup from one of my swipe views (LayoutTwo class which extends Fragment). I am having the code below, but when I press the button, nothing happens.. I think there is a problem with passing my views, but I am not sure.. Any ideas?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, null); 
    this.container = container;
    Button test = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.bButton);
    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            initiatePopupWindow();

        }
    });


    return root;
}
private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
                (ViewGroup) container.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);

        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        TextView mResultText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.server_status_text);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class LayoutTwo extends Fragment {

    private PopupWindow pw;
    private ViewGroup root;
    private Context C;
    private ViewGroup container;


    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutTwo f = new LayoutTwo();  

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, null); 
        this.container = container;
        Button test = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.bButton);
        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                initiatePopupWindow();

            }
        });


        return root;
    }
    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
                    (ViewGroup) container.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            View mainLayout = container.findViewById(R.id.linear);
            pw = new PopupWindow(mainLayout, 300, 470, true);

            pw.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            TextView mResultText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.server_status_text);
            Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pw.dismiss();
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [PopupWindow.showAtLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), the first parameter should be its **parent** view, not its own view.

Try doing this instead:

```
// assuming R.id.linear is the 'android:id' of your main view
View mainLayout = container.findViewById(R.id.linear);
pw.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

EDIT: For future reference, keep in mind that you could also get the root View by doing one of two things:

**Including** the status bar

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

**NOT Including** the status bar

```
((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)
```

Comment: thanks, I just don't fully understand what you mean. You mean for example the id of the linear layout where it is called from?

Comment: Yeah, that LinearLayout is the parent view of your PopupWindow.

Comment: Damn, I changed it to View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
                 (ViewGroup) container.findViewById(R.id.linear));
         
         pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
         
         pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);... But it still doesn't show up. The id linear is now the id of the main LinearLayout from layout_two.xml (I based myself on the example of Munish Kapoor: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/) if I replace layout by R.id.linear i get an error that this is not a View..

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I edited my answer accordingly. You have to use the LinearLayout object itself (not the id) as the first parameter to your showAtLocation() call.

Comment: Mmm, I tried it, but still doesn't give a popup.. there might be something wrong else? I'll update my question with the full java file..

Comment: Try using the inflater like this instead: LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: :( Still not.. could it be in this line: View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
                 (ViewGroup) container.findViewById(R.id.popup_element)); perhaps? I am getting the id from the container, but popup_element is an id from the popup_layout.xml... I don't know, am getting crazy here :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26202/discussion-between-crazylpfan-and-matthias-vanb)